# How can I handle dynamic content in external javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I have a website in several languages and it happens that there are some visitors who for some reason are viewing a page in a different language than that of their browser settings.
Therefore, if their browser language is one of those the site is translated into, I suggest they switch to their preferred language.
I do this with a div containing a message at the top of the page.

```
According to your settings, we suggest you to view the content of this page in the following language: {language link}.
{Denied option with link}
```

The message is shown in the current language (I have all the translations of course), while {language link} is taken from the user's settings. The javascript code is generated Serverside with PHP and managed by Javascript in the HTML

```
<script> 
// instructions loaded, matching user conditions...
</script>
```

Is there any way to manage it in an external js file? How to do? Obviously, I'm not interested in preparing n*n combinations of files and uploading the one that matches the visitor's situation.

How to do?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; are you asking how to redirect to a page based on a language selection?

Comment: No. The message contains everything. {language link} contains the name of the language and the link for the user. The user decides to click the suggestion's link or refuse the suggestion and continue browsing in the current language.

Comment: What are you asking then? How to display the appropriate message and link? Like by detecting the browser language and mapping that to the message/link? Personally I think this is an anti-pattern; just show the available translations.

Comment: Just edited my post to clearify. The Javascript code is generated Serverside with PHP and managed by Javascript in the HTML. I'm asking if there is a way to do it with an external .js file. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, write the language detection code in JS and use it to map to messages/links.

Comment: So, I need to write all N messages in JS code and decide the one to show?  N = number of languages available.

Comment: The messages and translations are all present in PHP and are handled server side, I don't copy them in JS (I don't think it's a smart decision). I'm trying to figure out if there is a solution with external file and how to do it.

Comment: All this is broken because of this: "_I suggest they switch to their preferred language._" --> They already did, by choosing a language that is different than the one you forced them to use in the first place. Insisting that your choice of language for them is the better choice, and then prompting them to ensure their choice is really what they want is, well, an interesting approach. Perhaps the solution is to allow the end user of your product to make choices based upon their own needs, but then allow them to do so unimpeded.

Comment: What's the purpose of putting it in an external JS file then? Render them into JS in an include file (or whatever PHP calls them). I'm still not really seeing what the question is--you keep saying the browser settings check is done server side but you want it to be done in JS, I keep saying do that work in JS, and I don't understand the disconnect.

Comment: The purpose is I'm using JS for a special cookie. Once a user tells me he wants that language, even if the language does not match the setting language, I do not ask him anymore. I didn't specify everything because I didn't want to bore people.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably write particular JavaScript server side that assigns data to a global variable, in addition to your external script.

In the server-rendered page, it'd look something like:

```
<script>
  var userSettingsLanguageLink = '{language link}';
</script>
```

And then in your external script, something like:

```
  if (userSettingsLanguageLink !== getBrowserLanguage())
  //...
```

Comment: Server side language is PHP. I check if user browser settings language (A) and page language (B) are different with PHP. Then, the suggestion link contains link to the current page in (A) language. I hope this clearify my post.